# jQuery/JS method chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I'm having a problem understanding chaining. I have this code fragment:

```
groups.appendTo(this.selectedList.add(this.availableList));
```

Initially, both `selectedList` and `availableList` are identical, and contain an HTML `ul` with a single `li` element. `groups` is another `ul` with 4 `li` elements. On completion, both `this.selectedList` and `this.availableList` have been modified, and contain the new list items.
How does this work, and what exactly is the `add` doing here? It doesn't add the contents of the available list to the selected list. I also thought that `add` returned a temporary object? And why is this code any better than:

```
groups.appendTo(this.AvailableList);
groups.appendTo(this.selectedList);
```

Thanks.

*EDIT*

The context is:

```
(function($) {
   $.widget("ui.multiselect", {
      options: {...},
      _func: function() {
         ... local 'this':
         groups.appendTo(this.selectedList.add(this.availableList));
      }
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: No - it's copied verbatim from the source (a multiselect plugin), which I've traced through on Firebug to get the results above.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about chaining is that you don't have to perform your selections multiple times and therefore gain performance. All jQuery-functions (plugins too) will return the selection (some will return an altered selection though) they performed on so you can just add another method in the chain like:

```
$('.classIHaveUsedVeryOften').append(foo).hide().addClass('bar');
```

In case you would write:

```
$(.classIHaveUsedVeryOften).append(foo);
$(.classIHaveUsedVeryOften).hide();
$(.classIHaveUsedVeryOften).addClass('bar');
```

jQuery would have to retrieve all of the matching elements three times. In case you have large DOM structures this can take quite some time actually (i.e. don't do this).

Another possibility of dealing with this issue would be putting your selection into a variable beforehand:

```
var $mySelection = $(.classIHaveUsedVeryOften);
$mySelection.append(foo);
$mySelection.hide();
$mySelection.addClass('bar');
```